# Custom metrics script on window instances in two different regions in two different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

```
 {
  "metrics": {
    "append_dimensions": {
      "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
    },
    "metrics_collected": {
      "LogicalDisk": {
        "measurement": [
          "Free Megabytes",
          "Used Megabytes"
        ],
        "resources": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Memory": {
        "measurement": [
          "Available MBytes",
          "Committed Bytes"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

I have applied a same  custom metrics   script on window instances in two different regions (one in N.vriginia and other in Ohio) in two different accounts.im getting data on cloudwatch in ohio region but im not getting data on N.virginia